# Vidalia i686 failure starting

Tags: vidalia, fedora

Download Vidalia i686 from https://people.torproject.org/~erinn/vidalia-standalone-bundles/, extract them to one folder, and executed start-vidalia in terminal in order to view the error, the error message say libssl and libcryto miss, after installing openssl-devel, no use at all, but after copying them to the vidalia Lib folder, it works. Well, I don't understand why this phenomenon happen? My OS is fedora 20 32bit Gnome livecd.